# String Concatenation using StringBuilder

Tags: java, spring, string, spring-boot

Is there better way of concatenating and creating a string object?

```
@Value("${key}")
private String key;

@Value("${uri}")
private String uri;

@Value("${search.url}")
private String searchUrl;

public void search(){

    String resourceUrl
      = new StringBuilder(uri).append(key).append(searchUrl).toString();

}
```

Comment: `String resourceUrl = uri + key + searchUrl;` is fine.

Comment: Thanks @PM77-1. That answers my question. Thanks Eng Fouad.